# multiply 2 diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that if i multiply 2 diagonal matrixes i get a diagonal matrix.
I understand the logic behind it but find it difficult to prove on paper.

I started with saying that a diagonal matrix Aij = 0 when i != j.
Then I declared 2 diagonal matrixes A,B of size n*n.

```
       n           i - 1           n
```

(AB)ij = Σ (Aik * Bkj) = Σ (Aik * Bkj) + Σ (Aik * Bkj)

```
     k = 1         k = 1         k=j+1
```

so the first part equals zero because Aik will be 0 becasuse k is bigger than i.
im stuck on the second part, how to show that the second part is also equal to 0, meaning what ranges to use on the sums.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ the two diagonal matrices of size $n$.  $C$ is the product of the two

We have 
$$C_{i,j}=\sum_{k=0}^n{A_{i,k}B_{k,j}}$$

We know that $A_{i,k} =0$ if $i \ne k$, and $B_{k,j} =0$ if $j \ne k$

$$C_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{i,k}B_{k,j}}=A_{i,i}B_{i,j}+A_{i,j}B_{j,j}$$

if $i \ne j$, $B_{i,j}=0$ and $A_{i,j}=0$
therefore $C_{i,j}=0$

Comment: can you explain how you got to : $$A_{i,i}B_{i,j}+A_{i,j}B_{j,j}$$

Comment: we know that the product $A_{i,k}B_{k,j}=0$, if at least one of them is nil. $A_{i,k}$ is nil when $i \ne k$ , and   $B_{k,j}$ is nil when $k \ne j$. So we remove all these element from the sum, and all we have are the cases when $k=i$ and $k=j$

Comment: the thing is I can't just say that just yet, we just learned this subject so we need to show the entire thing with calculations. can you please just show what ranges to use on the sums and i will explain why they are 0 except AiiBij and AijBjj ?

Comment: You understand the elements of the diagonal $A$ are $A_{i,i}$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$ , and the elements of the diagonal $B$ are $B_{j,j}$ with $1 \leq j \leq n$ ?

Comment: those are the elements that are not 0 right? at least not by definition but can still be 0.

Comment: These elements can be zeros and non-zeros. The rest of the matrix must be zeros. Therefore $A_{i,k}$ is guaranteed to be zero if... ??

Comment: In the first equation, isn't the sum supposed to start at k=1?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$C=AB$$ Where $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.

That is $a_{i,j}=0$ if $i\ne j$ and $b_{j,k}=0$ if $j\ne k$

The terms of $C$ are simply $$ c_{i,k}=\sum a_{i,j}b_{j,k}$$ which is zero unless   $i=j=k$

Thus $c_{i,i}$ are the only possibly non- zero terms which means  $C$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove in a shorter way:

If $i\ne j$, as $C_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{kj}$, each $k$ in this sum cannot be equal to *both* $i,j$, hence one (at least) of $A_{i,k}, B_{k,j}$ is $0$, and consequently all terms of this sum are $0$, which means $A_{ij}=0$ if $i\ne j$.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce the Kronecker symbol : $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$, $0$ otherwise.

Then $(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}\delta_{ik}\delta_{kj}$

If $i\neq j$ then $\delta_{ik}\delta_{kj} = 0$ for all $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. So, if $i\neq j$,  $(AB)_{ij} = 0$. Therefore, $AB$ is a diagonal matrix.